# AppBundle symfony 4

Tags: import, doctrine, entities, symfony4

I have a problem with **Symfony 4**, I want generate entities from an existing database with the command :

`php bin/console doctrine:mapping:import --force AppBundle xml`

But an error appears :

`Bundle "AppBundle" does not exist or it is not enabled. Maybe you forgot to  add it in the registerBundles() method of your App\Kernel.php file?`

I try to import in the file kernel.php in registerBundles() :

`new AppBundle/AppBundle();`

but undefined class and when I create it in src/AppBundle/AppBundle.php :

`<?php 
namespace AppBundle;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;
class AppBundle extends Bundle
{
}`

nothing change and when I retry the command :

`PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ClassNotFoundException: Attempted to load class "AppBundle" from namespace "App".
Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace? in /var/www/html/symfony/Mission3/src/Kernel.php:30`

I would like to know if it's possible to create a bundle like that or if it exists an other command to generate entities from an existing database.

Comment: What are you asking? What have you tried? Did you check whether `you forgot to add [AppBundle] in the registerBundles() method of your App\Kernel.php file?` If you want an answer, you need to provide a specific question and enough information about your problem for people to help you.

Comment: Do you understand your question when you read what you wrote? We neither ;). Follow the @divibisan advise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in SF4, The main application component is named 'App' by default and is not a bundle. 
You have to manually create a dummy bundle under src\ directory in order to use old doctrine:command related to bundle. 
see how to manually create a bundle [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles.html)

After that, you can import/generate mappings/entities using doctrine:commands and use them in the App main module space, or in those bundles.

The SF4 maker tool don't provide bundle creation yet ... But I suppose the SF4 developers consider it's not an urge must have requirement, because they want us to focus on putting most code in the bundle less App main module.

Answer (score 0):

In symfony 4 'AppBundle' is doesn't exist anymore. Try use 'App' instead 'AppBundle'