# Symfony 4 Doctrine, creating Entities from database table

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony4

New to Symfony here
I am following [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/reverse_engineering.html) tutorial about mapping db tables to entities. I created the `blog_post` and `blog_comment` tables in my db. 
I tried running this `php bin/console doctrine:mapping:import --force AppBundle xml` which spit out the following error.

```
Bundle "AppBundle" does not exist or it is not enabled. Maybe you forgot to 
add it in the registerBundles() method of your App\Kernel.php file?
```

My `doctrine.yaml` is pretty much out of the box.

Doctrine.yaml

```
doctrine:
dbal:
    # configure these for your database server
    driver: 'pdo_mysql'
    server_version: '5.7'
    charset: utf8mb4

    # With Symfony 3.3, remove the `resolve:` prefix
    url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: '%kernel.debug%'
    naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
    auto_mapping: true
    mappings:
        App:
            is_bundle: true
            type: annotation
            dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
            prefix: 'App\Entity'
            alias: App
```

I created the App.php Class under `src/Entity/` and added a line under `bundles.php` but still get an error. The line I added on bundles.php is
`App\Entity\App::class=>['all' => true],` since that is the defined namespace of my App.php class.

Another error I get is

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught 
Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ClassNotFoundException: Attempted to load 
class "App" from namespace "App\Entity\App".
Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace? in 
/var/www/html/quick_tour/src/Kernel.php:32
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AppBundle symfony 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49498788/appbundle-symfony-4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must use App rather than AppBundle on Symfony 4

Answer (score 1):

Found similar situation to mine in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49498788/appbundle-symfony-4) as well.

Since Symfony 4 Use App instead of Appbundle